# XSLT: Creating new attribute with value of another attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming one XML into another.
Let's say the XML we start from looks like this

```
<fruit id="123">
  <apple></apple>
  <banana></banana>
  <lemon></lemon>
</fruit>
```

Now in my transformed XML I want to create a new attribute with the value of the id attribute from my old XML.

I tried to do this like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="fruit">
    <xsl:attribute name="reference">
         <xsl:value-of select="fruit/@id"/>   
    </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
```

I get this error:

```
cannot create an attribute node whose parent is a document node
```

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong, since I don't understand the error.
A solution would be nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Document Nodes cannot have attributes, and you are not creating an element in the output tree for the attribute to be applied to.  A Document Node must also have a single Element child.

Something like the following should work.

```
<xsl:template match="fruit">
    <fruit>
        <xsl:attribute name="reference">
             <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>   
        </xsl:attribute>
    </fruit>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: In the template matching `fruit` you need to use `<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>` to select and output the value of the `id` attribute of the matched element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, I hadn't spotted that mistake when I pasted it.  I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you can't create an attribute node here, because there's no element for it to belong to.  Attribute nodes can only be created when you're inside an element (in the output sense) *and* you haven't yet created any child nodes (elements, text nodes, comments or processing instructions) under that element.

Aside from this, your XPath is wrong - you're inside a template matching the `fruit` element, so the path to the `id` attribute is just `@id`, not `fruit/@id`.

Comment: does this mean you can't add a new attribute to a document element?

Comment: @Tcanarchy a _document node_ is not an element.  In the XPath data model the document node is a kind of virtual node that forms the root of the whole tree.  The document node must have exactly one element child (the _document element_) but it can additionally have comments, processing instructions or whitespace-only text nodes before or after the single element (e.g. comments above the start tag of the document element).  You can add attributes to the document element, but not to the root document node.